# PHP - Insertar datos en mySQL (bajo Joomla 3.x)

Tags: php, array, joomla3

Buenas!

Quiero hacer algo bastante sencillo, guardar en mi base de datos información que tengo en variables php recogidas de un formulario (base de datos mysql y código ejecutado bajo Joomla3)

Con el código que os dejo me muestra siempre un error de sintaxis (que no encuentro). Antes me aparecia el error "Unkow column "x" on field list", pero ví que era por encerrar entre comillas una variable de un campo INT. Le quite las comillas y ahora aparece error de sintaxis.

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo? Gracias!

Os dejo la estructura y el código PHP:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Intenta quitar las comillas invertidas, en ocasiones MySQL me ha molestado por ello.

Comment: Si pongo comilla simple en lugar de grabar el valor de las variables de php graba literalmente la propia variable. Es decir, donde yo pongo '$v1' me graba literalmente $v1, en lugar del valor de la variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Las comillas invertidas **(`)** es parte de la sintaxis empleada desde el mismo MySQL PHPMyAdmin. Ahora bien, dado que dicho query está siendo empleado desde PHP para ejecutarse en MySQL, te recomiendo remover dichas comillas de los campos y usar la comillas simples **(')** o dobles **(")** utilizadas en PHP para valores tipo cadena o fecha. Ejemplo:

```
$variable = 'cadena';
$query = "INSERT INTO Tabla VALUES('valor', '" + $variable + "')";
```